# How do I retrieve the node name from XML in Flex / Actionscript

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have some data xml data that looks like this

```
<root xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test1.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <configuration>
    <CLICK/>
    <KLT/>
    <DETd/>
  </configuration>
</root>
```

I get a list of the configurations using

var results:XMLList = xml.configuration.*;

Now I want to loop over the XMLList and output CLICK, KLT, DETd etc. but how in XML do I get the node name as such

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XML:

```
<root>
    <parentNode>
        <childNode1>1</childNode1>
        <childNode2>2</childNode2>
        <childNode3>3</childNode3>
    </parentNode>
</root>
```

All you need to do is use `.name()` while iterating through `parentNode`'s `children()`.

```
for(var i:int=0;i<xml.children()[0].children().length();i++)
{
    var currentNode:XML = xml.children()[0].children()[i];
    trace(currentNode.name());
}

//childNode1
//childNode2
//childNode3
```

More:

1. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XMLList.html
2. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [name](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#name%28%29) as the accessor.

```
for each (var prop:XML in xml.configuration.*) 
{ 
    trace(prop.name());
}
```

You had `xml.configuration.*` listing what was needed, so you were half-way there. Just take each element as an XML in the iteration (with a for each loop).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the name() method on any XML node, like so:

```
for each(var n:XML in results){
    trace(n.name());
}
```

Will output:

```
CLICK
KLT
DETd
```