# how to find tag name of xml?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, tags

I'm trying to build a library project which will dynamically call some xml data.. This xml data may contain a button, and then add a button to the library project. Can anyone help me to find the tag name of the xml data?

Comment: Could you maybe post a sample of your XML data and what it is you exactly want to find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the name of an XML node using E4X, you use the name() function.

```
var xml:XML = new XML("<root><content>Stuff</content></root>");
trace(xml.child(0).name());
// Output: 'content'
```

The tricky part is usually navigating to the correct node. The basics of E4X navigation are too involved to go into here. You could take a look at the Adobe documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e72.html or Google [E4X](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ECMAScript%20for%20XML).

There are also any number of other questions similar to this. For example, here: [How do I retrieve the node name from XML in Flex / Actionscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163232/how-do-i-retrieve-the-node-name-from-xml-in-flex-actionscript)